# How to update to Neodynamic Thermal Label SDK version 7 from SDK version 3 in C#.Net application?

Tags: c#, wpf, thermal-printer, neodynamic

In one of my C#.Net application, I used the Thermal Label SDK version 3 to create the Label. Now because of some reasons, I want to update the Thermal Label SDK version to the latest that is [version 7](https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/ThermalLabel7.0/articles/about.html). When Updating the Thermal label SDK I can see a lot of changes are there compare to the previous version 3. The following are my doubts.

1. Unable to set the **Margin** for the **ThermalLabel**.

In Thermal label SDK 3, I can set the margin to the ThermalLabel like below. But in SDK version 7 those attributes are not there.

```
ThermalLabel tLabel = new ThermalLabel(UnitType.Inch, this.GetInches(labelCreator.ImageSize.Width), this.GetInches(labelCreator.ImageSize.Height));
tLabel.Margin.Top = 0.1;
tLabel.Margin.Left = 0;
tLabel.Margin.Right = 0;
tLabel.Margin.Bottom = 0;
```

2. Unable to set the **TextLines, Font.CharHeight, IsBuiltInFont** attributes for **TextItem**.

In Thermal label SDK 3, I can set above-mentioned attributes to the TextItem like below. But in SDK version 7 those attributes are not there.

```
TextItem txtField = new TextItem();
txtField.Font.IsBuiltInFont = !this.useSoftFont;
txtField.Font.CharHeight = fieldDef.FieldFont.Size;
txtField.TextLines = 2;
```

3. Unable to set **Rotate** attribute to the **BarCodeItem**.

In Thermal label SDK 3, I can set the Rotate attributes to the BarCodeItem like below. But in SDK version 7 those attributes are not there.

```
BarcodeItem dataMatrixItem = new BarcodeItem();
dataMatrixItem.Rotate = (Neodynamic.SDK.Printing.Rotate)Enum.Parse(typeof(Neodynamic.SDK.Printing.Rotate), fieldDef.Rotate);
```

I checked the documentation but I don't see anything related to that. If anyone knows how to do that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted the Neodynamic support team, the following is the response I got from them. I am posting it here because it might help someone.

Since v4, SDK is not backward compatible.

1. Margin are no longer supported, you have to specify the X and Y
   prop of each item
2. For TextItem font settings, you must use Font property. Read more
   on the help https://neodynamic.com/Products/Help/ThermalLabel7.0/articles/using-fonts.html
3. Set the RotationAngle prop of BarcodeItem obj

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation they don't have such properties for you to use

https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/ThermalLabel7.0/api/Neodynamic.SDK.Printing.ThermalLabel.html

https://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/ThermalLabel7.0/api/Neodynamic.SDK.Printing.TextItem.html

so you must contact their **support** for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.